# GMSCircle irregular borders in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps in which I created circle using below code but my circle's borders are irregular.My question is how to make it smooth like MKCircle

```
let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCentreCoordinate, radius: CLLocationDistance(radius))
            circ.fillColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            circ.strokeColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
            circ.strokeWidth = 2
            circ.map = self.mapView                
            let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(circ.bounds())
            mapView.animate(with: update)
```

when my radius is 30 meters it show me like this

[image]

when radius is 200+ meters it is like

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution??

Comment: this issue with me also when map zoom level more than 18.0. it GMSCircle became irregular shape.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was in GoogleMap 3.1.0, Update to GoogleMap 3.3.0, This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks buddy . I will check it